# ETL transformations in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a question regarding the most efficient method for data transformations. I have been tasked with performing ETL processes at my company and am the sole person responsible for the data.

I have extracted additional information from a DynamoDB and RDS using AWS Glue. I then read the table with Athena, created a view, and loaded it into Power BI using the Athena Connector.

My question is, what is the best way to perform transformations on the data, such as adding columns with rank functions and others? Should I use Pyspark in the transform part while running the job in Glue, or should I use SQL to add the columns in the Athena view? Or should I try something different?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's a very broad question and this doesn't have one solution, you can go with all the ways, but AWS preferred way is going with AWS Glue and it's ETL transformations.

There is also AWS EMR, but in the end it depends on the kind of transformations you need to do, the pricing, the amount of data and the latency that is required.

There is no clear answer to this question, only opinions (with the information given).